# update based on multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
PART  LATESTPART RATE  LATESTMONTHSALE status
A        X        100   2019-06-01        N
B        X        100   2019-07-01        N
C        Y        200   2019-08-01        N
D        Y        150   2019-08-01        N
E        X        100   2019-09-01        N
```

update status as "Y" of `PART` when `LATESTPART` is same and  `RATE` minimum
Eg. for `PART` C,D `LATESTPART` is same(Y) and  rate of 'PART' D is minimum(150) then update part D status "Y".

If rate is same then check `LATESTMONTHSALE`. Update status of the `PART` having lastest month. 
Eg. for `PART` A,B,E  `LATESTPART` is same(X) and rate is also same then update `PART`  E  because `2019-09-01` is latest date.

i want result as.

```
PART  LATESTPART RATE  LATESTMONTHSALE  status
A        X        100   JUN_19           N
B        X        100   JUL_19           N
C        Y        200   AUG_19           N
D        Y        150   AUG_19           Y
E        X        100   SEP_19           Y
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: Are you really storing dates as  `'JUN_19`, or you are using a regular `date`-like datatype?

Comment: Is the `PART` unique here?

Comment: yes part is unique

Comment: can you post the expected output of the table after the update is done? That will help understand the question better.

Comment: actually JUN_19  is a column name in table.according to condition LATESTMONTHSALE  is ,in which month a particular part sold.it may take as regulare date

Comment: status of part D and E updated as Y

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do this with a correlated subquery that filters on the latest records per `(part, latestpart)` tuple and a `not exists` condition that filters on the record that has the lowest `rate`.

```
update mytable t set status = 'Y'
where 
    t.latestmonthsale = (
        select max(t1.latestmonthsale)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.part = t.part and t1.latestpart = t.latestpart
    )
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.part = t.part 
            and t1.latestpart = t.latestpart
            and t1.latestmonthsale = t.latestmonthsale
            and t1.rate < t.rate
)
```

In SQLServer, you can also do this with `row_number()` and an updatable cte:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        status, 
        row_number() 
            over(partition by part, latestpart order by latestmonthsale desc, rate) rn
    from mytable
)
update cte set status = 'Y' where rn = 1
```

Comment: it update all part .conditions.. 1. check minimum rate. 2. if rate same then check latestmonthsale